Is there a way to compare equation in different form?
(a+1)^2 === a^2 + 2 a + 1 

gives false.
Is there a way to compare these two?
(*Step 1:Clear any existing definitions to avoid \
conflicts*)ClearAll[gmN1, roN1, roP1, RS, CL1, VD1, Vs, Vin, s, Av, \
gain]

(*Step 2:Define the equations with the new variable names*)

(*Equation 1*)
eqn1 = -gmN1*Vs + (VD1 - Vs)/roN1 + VD1/roP1 + s*CL1*VD1 == 0;

(*Equation 2*)
eqn2 = (Vin - Vs)/RS == gmN1*Vs + (Vs - VD1)/roN1;

(*Step 3:Solve the system of equations for VD1 and Vs*)
solution = Solve[{eqn1, eqn2}, {VD1, Vs}]

(*Step 4:Display the solution in Traditional Form for readability*)
TraditionalForm[solution]
gain = (VD1/Vin) /. solution
Av = Replace[gain, {x_} :> x, {0, -2}] // FullSimplify

VD1Vin[s_] := ((gmN1 + 1/roN1)/
    RS)/((gmN1 + 1/roN1)/
     roN1 + (gmN1 + 1/roN1 + 1/RS)*(1/roN1 - 1/roP1 - s*CL1))
VD1Vin[s] // FullSimplify

The formula I want to test is actually VD1Vin == Av

One way: Expand[(a + 1)^2] == a^2 + 2 a + 1

Write it as eq = (a + 1)^2 == a^2 + 2 a + 1 then either Reduce[eq] or Simplify[eq] gives True

PossibleZeroQ applied to the difference would be one way.


Please don't create new unnecessary tags. 2. Please use search before posting a question. For example, see links in the comments here


@Nasser  The formula I want to test is actually VD1Vin == Av

@user1066 The formula I want to test is actually VD1Vin == Av

@DanielLichtblau The formula I want to test is actually VD1Vin == Av

I presume you mean VD1Vin[s] == Av?

Usually you can do the following. Equations are equivalent if the following holds. But be aware of possible zeros of any denominator that appears in equations.
It does not matter if === or == is used it this case.
Hopefully the code is self-explanatory.
eq1 = x^2 + 4 y^2 == 5 - (x (7 + 4 y) + 3 y);
eq2 = 1 + 2/3 x/y + 1/y == (5 - (x + y)^2 - 7 x)/(3 y^2);

Numerator@Factor@First@SubtractSides@eq1 == 
 Numerator@Factor@First@SubtractSides@eq2

Numerator@Factor@First@SubtractSides@eq1 === 
 Numerator@Factor@First@SubtractSides@eq2


True

True

